# to convert a plain js function to jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have a js function and this is working when the page loads but i tried to convert into jQuery & not working now. please help me out and describe why isn't this working.

```
window.onload = function updatePreviewHTML() {

              alert("hello");   }
```

as i converted this into jQuery but it's not working

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

            alert("Hello");         });
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which version of jQuery .js file have you included in your html code?

Comment: Does your browser report any javascript errors?  Are you using any other javascript libraries or just jQuery?

Comment: Maybe the OP didn't include the jquery script in the HTML?

Comment: @Aziz : version 1.6 (jquery-1.6.2.min.js)

Comment: You must have either a JS error in your page or a problem with the correct inclusion of jQuery because your jQuery code is fine and will work if the other things are done correctly.

Comment: @All : solved & it was my silly mistake. i had include the jQuery.js files below of my defined js file. now i placed it below the jquery.js files and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ jfriend00's guessing was right and i noticed that the js file is included above the jQuery's js files and that is why i was getting error.

I included my js file just below the jQuery files and it starts running well.